# I have tried to use ORB feature extraction but I am unable to display the features

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('BottleNEW.jpg',0)

# Initiate STAR detector
orb = cv2.ORB()

# find the keypoints with ORB
kp = orb.detect(img,None)

# compute the descriptors with ORB
kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)

# draw only keypoints location,not size and orientation
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
plt.imshow(img2)
plt.show()
```

I copied this code from the OpenCV documentation but the plt.imshow does not display anything.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You declared your detector wrong. When you want to use the ORB detector you must clarify `orb = cv2.ORB_create()`. Also, I found that there really wasn't a need to compute your keypoints after you detect them, just draw them on the image. Here is my code below

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('BottleNEW.jpg',0)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

# Initiate STAR detector
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

# find the keypoints with ORB
kp = orb.detect(img,None)

# draw only keypoints location,not size and orientation
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, None, color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
plt.imshow(img2)
plt.show()
```